# How to describe the difference between on demand and on the fly?

Tags: word-difference

One of my colleague suddenly asked me this question. As an IT person, I know roughly what is on demand and on the fly, and inside my gut I feel that on demand and on the fly are two different things. But because they're often used together, I have a hard time to describe to him what *exactly* the difference between them. In the simplest definition possible, I feel like *on demand* is the way user requests the content, and *on the fly* is the way the system delivers the content to the user. But I still feel something is missing or inaccurate. I feel like *on the fly* indeed has intersection with *on demand*, but they also have their own separated things. But I can't quite grasp what are those. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is not subtle. The phrase **on demand** means "when required", whereas **on the fly** means "without interruption". Illustrating this with two examples:

Your shop has a price list of stock items, so you can provide a price **on demand**. But if someone requests the price of a non-stock item, lets say by telephone, and during the call you quickly look up the item on your supplier's website, you can give a price **on the fly**, without the customer knowing what you did. However you would be unable to supply this item **on demand** as you don't have it in stock.

If you have been called out to give an immediate demonstration of your company's software, that would be **on demand**. Now if you notice a fault with its set-up just before the meeting starts, and quickly edit the configuration files, you would have fixed it **on the fly**.

Comment: I see. So on demand refers to something that we already have (or prepared), while on the fly conjure things from thin air. :D This clears things up. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

From oxforddictionaries.com:

*On Demand* is `As soon as or whenever required.` (i.e. without waiting.)

*On The Fly* is `While in motion or progress.` (i.e. without needing to stop the current process)